# ARIMA Model in R - datacamp exercise -

Tags: r, statistics, arima, autoregressive-models, sarimax

in a datacamp exercise it seems to me not clear at all the answer

1. We have the data: globaltemp , provide by asta package, also I use astsa package functions
2. The exercise says that evaluate this data  using sarima and decide which of the two models provide on the bottom have the best fit:

sarima(globtemp,1,1,1)
AIC and BIC values:  -1.716773  and -1.630691, respectively

(graphic result with asta package for sarima(globtemp,1,1,1) is here)
[image]

sarima(globtemp,0,1,2)
AIC and BIC values: -1.723268     and  -1.637185, respectively
(graphic result with asta package for sarima(globtemp,0,1,2) is here)
[image]

Datacamp says the model with the best fit is the second. However, the model with the less AIC and BIC value is sarima(globtemp,1,1,1). Why the correct answer is the second model? Is it a mistake there?

Thanks for your time!

I look at the AIC and BIC values, and I expect that the first model: sarima(globaltemp,1,1,1) is the best model in comparison of sarima(globtemp,0,1,2); however, in datacamp, it says that the best is sarima(globtemp,0,1,2)

Comment: AIC and BIC are not exactly the same as quality of fit.  I would describe them as "quality of fit penalized by the number of predictor variables."  Perhaps the exercise wants you to compare MSE or RMSE instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both models are pretty similar but I guess the simpler the better due to the negligible difference in AIC and BIC values.

In this case ARIMA(0,1,2) its simpler because it lacks the autoregresive component `p` in the formulation ARIMA(p,d,q).

See [fpp2](https://otexts.com/fpp2/non-seasonal-arima.html) for more info.

Comment: Vyago, Thanks a lot! I really appreciate your reply. It makes sense to me. Thanks!